# Blender Rigid Bodies don't touch

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am trying to make a 0 gravity scene, I'm trying to make a spaceship (which as a passive rigid body) drift into a small collection of asteroids. The problem I am facing now is the Asteroids don't interact with the mesh, even after changing the settings from convex hull to mesh (which did solve a completely different issue that was causing the asteroids to randomly fly in a direction when the objects are very far apart) Regardless there is this tiny gap between the two objects that I cannot seem to get rid of. It's almost like the rigid body of the starship as become desynced from the rest of the mesh, which if I could somehow make it visible and edit the rigidbody myself I would. What I currently need is just something that can get rid of that tiny gap. Also if it is relevant: Editing the margin doesn't seem to have any effect no matter what number I make it, high, low, or 0.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error the solution was the asteroids had a lot of unapplied ,modifiers on them so the mesh that Blender saw was not what I was seeing. After Applying the modifiers the asteroids now behave properly.